# Only last `InputForm` output is displayed in desktop version of Mathematica 11?

Tags: bugs, output-formatting, output, mathematica-online

**Bug present at least up to version 11.0.0**

> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support and for bringing this issue to our attention.
>   Our development team is aware of the issue and working on it.

---

```
a // InputForm
b // InputForm
```

Gives me

[image]

in `"11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"` on my desktop and laptop computers. You can see that only the last output using `InputForm` is displayed. The web-app ( https://mathematica.wolframcloud.com/app ) does what I expect:

[image]

This only happens with `InputForm`, other `*Form`s display all outputs.

I must have some bad settings, but I cannot figure out what could be the cause.
The Suggestions Bar is off and init.m is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: It is not new, (10.4 too) yet I haven't though about that!

Comment: I would consider this a bug then.

Comment: I see. Since the web app behaves differently, I think we can finally consider this a bug/inconsistency between the two ;). What a great thing to have this second opinion.

Comment: I filed a bug report.

Comment: @masterxilo Any response to the report?

Comment: @Alan Not yet. However, their bug database and fixing process seems quite solid. When something that you reported is fixed in a future update,  you get a message.  I will reproduce such an eventual reply here.